# Ember.js & Ruby On Rails: Already Initialized Constant APP_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-cli

I have been familiarizing with Ember JS, and Ember-CLI. I was attempting to follow this [DevMynd Ember-CLI/Rails Tutorial](https://devmynd.com/blog/2014-7-rails-ember-js-with-the-ember-cli-redux-part-1-the-api-and-cms-with-ruby-on-rails) when I ran into an error. Now first off I should say I am not incredibly familiar with both ember and ruby on rails (more so with ember than rails) but I was exploring some new territory. Whenever I run `rails server` I get the following error message:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/tylerwendlandt/Development/EmberJS/bizniz/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of  APP_PATH was here
```

The part I find most curious is that it seems to say that I have defined the `APP_PATH` more than twice, but in the same spot. I've posted what I have so far and the corresponding issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/twendlandt/DevMyndTutorial). Any advice?

Comment: fwiw this is just a warning and shouldn't prevent the rails server from running.

Comment: @Beerlington ah yes - I guess I didn't take that into consideration. I don't know why the server is exiting then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though there was a small error in the tutorial I was following, I imagine it was a typo. I just had to move my `grape.rb` file from `app/config/initializers/grape.rb` to `config/initializers/grape.rb`. And move `contacts.rb` from `app/controllers/api/contacts.rb` to `app/controllers/api/v1/contacts.rb`. Works fine now, no warnings either.